# How to make multiple lines in ToC horizontally align?

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, tocloft

For single line, the content aligned nicely, but that's not the case when the it contains multiple lines. The alignment is odd:

[image]

So how can I make them align nicely?

**Mimimum Example**

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksdepth=3]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%define new colors
\definecolor{dark-red}{rgb}{0.4,0.15,0.15}
\definecolor{dark-blue}{rgb}{0.15,0.15,0.4}
\definecolor{medium-blue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}

%set up color for table of contents
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks, linkcolor={medium-blue},
    citecolor={dark-blue}, urlcolor={medium-blue}
}

\usepackage{tocloft}

%preven linebreak between subsection header and its content
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{3pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{3pt}{}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{8em} % Set numwidth of section
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{12em} % Make subsection numwidth the same as section
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{\cftsecindent} % Make subsection indent the same as section

\tableofcontents 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

    \newpage
    \phantomsection
    \section*{Problem 4.}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}
    {
        \numberline{Problem 4.}Let $T$ be a tree with $n > 1$ nodes. What is the maximum number of degrees one vertex $T$ can have?
        What his the minimum number of degree one vertex $T$ can have? Justify both answers.
    }
    Something
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this specific example, you need to remove the spurious space contained in your `\addcontentsline` definition:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}
{% <------ Required
    \numberline{Problem 4.}Let $T$ be a tree with $n > 1$ nodes. What is the maximum number of degrees one vertex $T$ can have?
    What his the minimum number of degree one vertex $T$ can have? Justify both answers.
}
```

[image: ToC]

Also note that `hyperref` complains about: "Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing 'math shift' on input line XXX". This is because of using math content `$ $` within the ToC entry, which eventually end up in the PDF bookmarks. To get rid of this, `hyperref` provides the conditional `\texorpdfstring{<tex-string>}{<pdf-string>}`. You would use it in the following way:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}
{% <------ Required
    \numberline{Problem 4.}Let \texorpdfstring{$T$}{T} be a tree with 
    \texorpdfstring{$n>1$}{n>1} nodes. What is the maximum number of degrees 
    one vertex \texorpdfstring{$T$}{T} can have? What his the minimum number 
    of degree one vertex \texorpdfstring{$T$}{T} can have? Justify both answers.
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for a very quick solution. It works nicely now. I'm surprised how detailed you are, you even noticed the little space of those mathematics symbols ;) Amazing!

Comment: @Chan: You're welcome! If this answered your question, consider [accepting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) it.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance. Have been busy with school lately. Once again, thanks a lot ;)